# Image conversion fails for bitmap images

Tags: filepicker.io

BMP image is here: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/fdsYv4NSaCGUefBAQmER

And the code to reproduce the failure:

```
var fpfile = { url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/fdsYv4NSaCGUefBAQmER',
    filename: 'customers.jpg', mimetype: 'image/jpeg', isWriteable: false, size: 629454};
console.log("Converting...");
/*an  element where we can display the resulting image*/
var result = document.getElementById("convert-result");
filepicker.convert(fpfile, {width: 200, height: 200},
    function(new_FPFile){
        console.log(new_FPFile.url);
        result.src = new_FPFile.url;
    }
);
```

Unclear what I am doing wrong here, any help would be most appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently support .bmp's for conversion, but we're in the process of adding it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to exclude bitmaps from the filepicker js so users dont upload them?

Comment: You can specify specific mimetypes or extensions that you want to allow in the options to the filepicker.pick() call, or you can check the mimetype on the FPFile that is returned and have a code flow that behaves differently

Comment: What do you mean exclude them by default? We wouldn't want to prevent people from uploading .bmp files just because our conversion feature doesn't currently support them, but using the mimetype or extension filter you can control this per the needs of your application